# FullCalendar VDOM already loaded

Tags: jquery, npm

When full calendar 5.5.1 is loaded i got error "FullCalendar VDOM already loaded" i even googled but did not find something suitable. am using NPM for web pack build system for this.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was instantiating `@fullcalendar` in Laravel's app.js and using the CDNs on the blade. I removed the `@fullcalendar` from app.js and solved the issue.

Try to find all references of fullcalendar and remove unnecessary ones

Answer (score 0):

rimeng working with FullCalendar 4.1, instead of installing the latest version of FullCalendar, try installing v4.1.

```
npm i @fullcalendar/core@4.1.0
npm i @fullcalendar/interaction@4.1.0
npm i @fullcalendar/daygrid@4.1.0
npm i @fullcalendar/timegrid@4.1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have both:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar-scheduler@5.10.1/main.min.js"></script>
```

and

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.10.1/main.min.js"></script>
```

If you include "fullcalendar-scheduler" then you do not need to include "fullcalendar" as well. Having both will cause this error.